# Передвижение персонажа в Pyglet

Tags: python

Я недавно познакомился с PyGlet.
Я хочу вывести на экран персонажа и управлять им, но у меня он просто стоит на месте.
Вот код:

```
window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 600)
player = pyglet.resource.image('data/RedPlayer.png')
playerX = 250
playerY = 250
playerSpeed = 3

@window.event
def on_key_pressed(symbol, modifires):
    if symbol == key.W and playerY > 0:
        playerY -= playerSpeed
    elif symbol == key.S and playerY < 575:
        playerY += playerSpeed
    elif symbol == key.A and playerX > 0:
        playerX -= playerSpeed
    elif symbol == key.D and playerY < 775:
        playerY += playerSpeed

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    player.blit(playerX, playerY)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Внутри функции on_key_pressed переменные playerX, playerY - локальные. У вас скорее всего еще и ошибку в консоль кидает при нажатии на кнопки.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.